# Django models: Access to a multilevel link between tables

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have a problem to access certain data in my models.

I have a `User` model giving its `id` to a `Profile` model which is giving its `id` to a `ProfileA` model.

And when I create a `User` it automatically creates a `Profile`.

Here is my `user_model`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from .model_custom_user_manager import CustomUserManager


class User(AbstractUser):
    """auth/login-related fields"""
    is_a = models.BooleanField('a status', default=False)
    is_e = models.BooleanField('e status', default=False)

    # objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

My `profile_model`:

```py
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.db.models.signals import post_save 
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    """non-auth-related/cosmetic fields"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    nationality = CountryField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

"""receivers to add a Profile for newly created users"""
@receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
      if created:
          Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

And what I'm trying to do is create a `ProfileA` when a `Profile` is created AND when a `User` has `is_a==True`.

Here is my `profilea_model`:

```py
from django.db import models
from .model_profile import *
from django.db.models.signals import post_save 
from django.dispatch import receiver

class ProfileA(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile_a')
    biography = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.profile)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile) 
def create_profile_profile_a(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created & Profile.user.is_a == True:
        ProfileA.objects.create(profile=instance)
```

And when I try creating a `User` with Postman:

```json
{
    "username":"Pepe",
    "password":"Yolo1234",
    "first_name":"Pepe",
    "last_name":"Pepito",
    "email":"pepe@yolo.com",
    "is_a":true,
    "is_e":false
}
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError at /users/
'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'is_a'
```

I've tried a lot of things but nothing woks and using the DjangDocs I can't understand.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **instance** argument of the **create_profile_profile_a** function is the instance of Profile which can be easily pointed to User and further get the target attribute **is_a**.

The receiver part in profilea_model should change to:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile) 
def create_profile_profile_a(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created & instance.user.is_a == True:
        ProfileA.objects.create(profile=instance)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling I was doing something wrong like this ><